# I need help factoring quadratics.

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I need help factoring $x^4-2x^2-3=0$. I do not know how to factor this disguised quadratic.

Comment: @Chief123: What if you let $x^2 = w$?

Comment: Yes we should substitute. @Moo

Comment: Do you see how to solve using that hint? Try it.

Comment: Yes I knew it was. I factored it to (u-3)(x+1)=0, u=x^2. I do not know what to do next, @SS_C4

Comment: Well, you now have $u = 3, -1$ and $x = \pm u^{1/2}$. So, $x = \pm \sqrt{3}, ~ \pm i$.

Answer (score 1):

take $y=x^2$ hence you have $y^2-2y-3=0$ hance $(y-3)(y+1)=0$

Comment: it's possible to simplify further to $(x^2-3)(x^2+1)=(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{3})(x^2+1)$

Comment: i suppose if it's over reals

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Rewrite $-2x^2$ as $-3x^2+x^2$ and group.

More specifically, $x^4-2x^2-3$ is equivalent to $x^4-3x^2+x^2-3$.

Can you proceed?

Comment: it's $2x^2$ . Please edit.

Comment: Done, thanks @WinVineeth